# jQuery function to update iFrame content on input change

Tags: jquery, iframe, find, onchange

I'm trying to update the contents of an iframe, when an input with the same ID is updated.

The content inside of an iframe with an ID of "preview"

```
<span id="mainheadertext">This is the iFrame content</span>
```

The input box in question:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="mainheadertext" name="mainheadertext">
```

My jquery:

```
$('input').on('input', function() {
    $("#preview").contents().find($(this).attr("id")).html($(this).val());
});
```

I believe it has something to do with my find, but I can't seem to figure it out.

Thanks!

Comment: I do not think you can effect the content of an iframe this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your find you just put the id you're looking for without the "#" to tell you're looking for an id (vs a class or a tag for example). It should be like this:

```
$("#preview").contents().find("#"+$(this).attr("id")).html($(this).val());
```

Maybe not the whole answer, but it's at least a first step.

Answer (score 0):

The source of the iframe is a different document/DOM. You can manipulate the iframe in your current document, but not the content of the iframe's document. What you could do is create a parameterized function in the iframe document and pass reload the iframe from the main document passing in your data on the querystring/URL.

Comment: i think you might need to provide an example for this to be most helpful. :D

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the jQuery prefix for ID (`#`) at the start of the `.find(...` :

```
$("#preview").contents().find("#"+$(this).attr("id")).html($(this).val());
```

**fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/20h3xwsz/1/**